# T-SQL query to check number of existences

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have next approximate tables structure:

```
accounts:
ID INT,
owner_id INT,
currency_id TINYINT
```

related to

```
clients:
ID INT
```

and

```
currency_types:
ID TINYINT,
name NVARCHAR(25)
```

I need to write a stored procedure to check existence of accounts with specific currency and all others, i.e. client can have accounts in specific currency, some other currencies and both.

I have already written this query:

```
SELECT
    ISNULL((
    SELECT 1
    WHERE EXISTS
    (
        SELECT 1
        FROM [accounts] AS A, [currency_types] AS CT
        WHERE
            A.[owner_id] = @client -- sp param
        AND A.[currency_id] = CT.[ID]
        AND CT.[name] = N'Ruble'
    )), 0) AS [ruble],
    ISNULL((
    SELECT 1
    WHERE EXISTS
    (    
        SELECT A.[ID]
        FROM [accounts] AS A, [currency_types] AS CT
        WHERE
            A.[owner_id] = @client 
        AND A.[currency_id] = CT.[ID]
        AND CT.[name] != N'Ruble'
    )), 0) AS [foreign]
```

Is it possible to optimize it? I'm new to (T)SQL, so thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such query requires one SELECT less:

```
RETURN ISNULL((SELECT 1
    WHERE
        EXISTS
        (
            SELECT 1
            FROM [accounts] AS A, [currency_types] AS CT
            WHERE
                A.[owner_id] = @client 
            AND A.[currency_id] = CT.[ID]
            AND CT.[name] != N'Ruble'

        )
    ), 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems pretty reasonable to me, EXISTS will give good performance for this kind of thing.

Do you have a reason for thinking it needs to be optimised? Is it performing badly?

The key thing to ensure is that you have suitable indexes (e.g. on accounts.[owner_id], CT.ID obviously is a PK)

Comment: @AdaTheDev: I'm new to SQL so just worry because query has 3 SELECTs.. and both WHERE conditions are very similar so maybe they could be split in something single but complex.

Comment: The outer select won't cost much at all (negligible). To achieve what you want, I actually think that approach is fine - can't see an easy way to achieve the same result. Complexity, usually makes things worse as it can make it harder for SQL Server to optimise the query as well